# Is this proper to say in the email?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My supervisor came out to monitor my work today and I'm now writing a thank you note to her.

In the end, I put it as follows.
"I also appreciate your comments on *** activity and how to maximize profits. Our team will work them out going forward."

Before hitting the "send" button, I want to ensure that "Our team will work them(your comments) out going forward" is correct and polite. Is there a way to put it in a better way? I just want to send out a message that our team takes your advice seriously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not *work out* comments.

You can say that your team will take the supervisor's comments into consideration. Or, if they are instructions then you can say that you will follow them or carry them out (or implement them).

Answer (score 0):

You can say it like: ""Our team will work them out effectively and efficiently going forward". Using words like 'efficient' and 'effective' seem like a good idea in your case as these words are often used in formal context.